# Is there any easier way to scrape this description?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying scrape the following description(Marked in red). At the moment my code does scrape that description but seems quite tedious has some html tags getting scraped with it. Is there any easier way around this ?

[image]

my code

```
given_link = "https://www.girodisc.com/Front-Rotors-for-Audi-Lamborghini_p_6541.html"
driver.get(given_link)
try:
    return driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#rTabs > div:nth-child(3) > div').get_attribute("innerHTML").replace("&nbsp;","").replace("<div>","").replace("</div>","").replace("<span>","").replace("</span>","").replace("<br>","").replace('<span style="font-size: 14pt;">','')
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception was raised",e)
    return "EMPTY"
```

Following output(scraped description)is an example of tags mentioned above in scraped description

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;">Important note regarding front brake pads:
our rotors work for cars with both iron and carbon ceramic rotors,
however they will require switching from the unique factory pad shape to
the more common "D1405" pad shape in the front. Please contact us if
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is overkill for this. Make a HTTP GET request to retrieve the HTML of the page, parse it via BeautifulSoup, get the human readable text of the tag that makes up the entire description via `get_text` (separate navigable strings by two newlines.)

```
def main():
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

    url = "https://www.girodisc.com/Front-Rotors-for-Audi-Lamborghini_p_6541.html"

    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    soup = Soup(response.content, "html.parser")

    print(soup.select_one("div.item").get_text("\n\n"))


main()
```

Comment: Presumably return 0 is for the sys.exit. Is there any guidance you could point me to please detailing the benefits of this approach?

Comment: The `return 0` and `sys.exit` is just a habit of mine to make Python scripts play a bit nicer when executed via Bash (some conditional execution in Bash depends on the exit code of a script, so it's nice to be explicit when running Python in that context), but it's not strictly required for this example. I've edited my example to just include the required parts.

Comment: If you're referring to my use of requests and BeautifulSoup, the advantage is that you don't need to use a heavy third-party library like Selenium to get the information you want to scrape. Granted, requests and BeautifulSoup are also third-party, but they're not so big, and you likely already have them installed. Additionally, the script will take less time to run, since you don't have to spin up a webdriver and scrape the page in real-time.